# PhantomJS returns wrong text

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, phantomjs

I have a weird problem with PhantomJS. I installed the `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` version on Ubuntu and I prepared a simple script to download HTML.

*get-website.js*

```
"use strict";
var system = require('system');
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

When i run `phatomjs get-website.js http://example.com` everything works fine and I get the result. But on the downloaded page there is a table loaded through JS and numbers from this table are incorrect. Table is downloaded correctly but numbers inside are wrong. For example there is `+450` instead `5.5`.

If I delete `page.settings.userAgent` line then the JS table is not downloaded at all.

I tried windows version too and it works precisely.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest you switch to Puppeteer. PhantomJS is not maintained anymore. In any case, it doesn't look like your problem has anything to do with PhantomJS but with how the website loads.

Comment: @DavidT Thanks, I already tried Chrome headless mode and there is the same problem. So it can be a website problem? For example it's this 1X2 full time table on [link](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga/valencia-barcelona-KC1yPEKJ/)

Comment: Can you update your question with the Chrome Headless attempt as well? You're attempting to get dynamic content that loads via AJAX, so you have to wait until the page fully loads etc.